# Autolayout for animations and views not initially on screen?

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout

I love autolayout and I've gotten past the intiail frustration for the most part. But one thing I don't understand is how to use it for a situation where you start with a view off screen and want to animate it on screen.

How can I set constraints for a view that is not on screen yet? because it's not on screen I can't enable variable height and width by sticking to the layout guide that covers the phone distances for you.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can change the position of the view by changing the constant of the constraint, or you can animate the layer, without changing the frame of the view. Take a look at this tutorial http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html

Answer (score 2):

FYI: You can have IBOutlet of constraints.

Now,Suppose you have one view whose width is 100 and height is 100.

If you wants to animate this view by changin it's width and height using autolayout, you need to perform following steps.

**Step 1:** Give width-height constraints to that view.(i.e.Width=100,Height=100).

**Step 2:** Take IBOutlet of that view's constraints in your ViewController.

**Step 3:** Whenever you wants to change it's width and height with animation, change the `constant` property of that constraint.

**Ex:**

```
widthContraint.constant = 50
heightContraint.constant = 50
```

**Step 4:** After changing constant, call layoutSubviews() method in animation block to perform animation.

**Ex:**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutSubviews()
    })
```

This will change view's width and height from `100` to `50` in `2.0` seconds.

**For the view that is not on screen:**

Make width and height of that view to **0**.
Then increase it to whatever you wants.

Comment: Well damn. This makes things much, much easier. How did I not connect the dots on this?

Comment: Sorry, but  I didn't get you, could you please explain.? Which dots you are saying about.?

Comment: It's just a figure of speech. Connecting the dots means to piece things together for a full understanding.

Comment: @TonyFriz, Oh yes, I got you.